# How to use this library in Android?

Tags: android, setup-project, android-actionbar

I want to make some ActionBar for my application using this library: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar but I don't know how to import it in my android project. There is no jar file. How can I do?

Flo

Comment: I am having this problem too!

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure you're using the latest version of the Android SDK, things have improved dramatically within the last few months.

1. Install the android-actionbar source code, either downloading it and unpacking it, or (preferably) using git to clone the repository on your system.

   (I strongly recommend using the mimic-native-api branch as it is the most up to date.)
2. Import the android-actionbar project into Eclipse. Note that the library's .project file is located in android-actionbar/actionbar. There is a small sample project in android-actionbar/actionbarexample as well.

   The project's library setting should already be set, but you can confirm this by right-clicking on the android-actionbar project in Eclipse, choosing Properties, and confirming that "Is Library" is enabled in the Android settings category.
3. In Eclipse, right-click on the project that you want to use the action bar library in, and choose Properties. Select the "Android" category in the list on the left. In the "Library" settings on the right, click the "Add..." button and select the android-actionbar library project.

---

Tip: I've found Eclipse can get a bit squirrely when you edit library code, if you run into errors that don't want to go away, use Project > Clean... to remove the R.java files, etc. ...then refresh your package explorer and rebuild.

Comment: I have this problem too, but on Step 1 where to install? and how to import the android-actionbar project into Eclipse? Sorry, for the noob questions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject and http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject. The first link explains how to create a Library project: you probably just need to take the github zip file, expand it and then add it to Eclipse. You can then import it into your own project in Eclipse.

Comment: I've ever read this. The problem is the zip file doesn't contain project file, so I can't import it as a project to add it as a library.

Comment: @user420574 The project in your link does look like an android project. However you can also create a new project out of the source code provided, then set it as a library and reference it in your project. Study TickTackToe example which came with Eclipse.

Comment: As @Lumis said, you will need to expand the zip file, copy the contents of the `actionbar` folder out to your file system then import that folder into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the source into your project folder and add each file as a new class

Comment: didn't work "The action bar component is an Library Project. This means that there's no need to copy-paste resources into your own project, simply add the action bar component as a reference to any project."