# Can't loop Bitmap in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, html-parsing

Really i tried many ways but withouth success! I can't loop the bitmap parsed from a webpage in my listview. My goal is parsing a webpage with some articles and for each articles display in a listview its title and image. I can display right now the title of each post and only the first image of the first article. I can't display for all. I don't understand where i wrong. Anyone can help me? I post the MainActivity and the Adapter activity.

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public static final String TAG_TITOLI = "titoli";
    private static final String TAG_IMMAGINE = "immagine";
    ListView lista;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public ImageView immagine;
    public ImageView logoimg;

    static final String BLOG_URL = "http://www.multiplayer.it";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.main_lista);//recupero lista da id



        //View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.riga_listview, null);
        //immaginebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.immaginebtn);
        //creo ed eseguo l'asynctask
        ParsingPaginaWeb parsing = new ParsingPaginaWeb();
        parsing.execute("");

        // Immagine btn
        /*immaginebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Logo AsyncTask
                new Logo().execute();
            }
        });*/
        //new Logo().execute();

         // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String titoli = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.riga_listview_titolo)).getText().toString();
                    immagine = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TITOLI, titoli);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_IMMAGINE, bitmap);
                    //in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, cont);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });

    }

    private class ParsingPaginaWeb extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        ArrayList<String> titoli; //lista dei titoli
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); 
        //ArrayList<String> content; //lista delle descrizioni

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {   
            //prima di eseguire il parsing inizializzo gli arraylist
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Multiplayer.it");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Caricamento articoli...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
            bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); 
            //content = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div.news-col-0 h3"); //per multiplayer.it Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div.news-col-0 h3"); per ftv #comunePartINI > option
                for(Element sezione : nodeBlogStats)
                {
                    titoli.add(sezione.text());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // In caso di errore
                Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING");
            }
            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            // dopo che ho eseguito il parsing mostro i dati nella listview
            // usando il custom array adpater ParsingArrayAdapter
            ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli, bitmap);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            new Logo().execute();
        }


    }

    // Classe per caricamento immagini..

    // Logo AsyncTask

    private class Logo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Immagini");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading images...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                // Using Elements to get the class data 
                //Elements img = document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]");
                // Locate the src attribute
                for(Element img : document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]")) {
                    String ImgSrc = img.attr("src");
                // Download image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(ImgSrc).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set downloaded image into ImageView
            logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

           // ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli);
           // lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ParsingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    //ID and resources references
    private final static int LAYOUT = R.layout.riga_listview;
    private final static int TITOLO = R.id.riga_listview_titolo;
    private final static int IMMAGINE = R.id.imageView1;

    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap ; 

    ArrayList<String> titoli; //lista dei titoli

    Context c; //context
    LayoutInflater inflater; //layout inflater

    public ParsingArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> titoli, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap)
    {
        super(context,TITOLO);
        this.c = context;
        this.titoli = titoli;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return titoli.size(); //List lenght 
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos,View view,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CacheRiga cache; //cache
        if(view==null)
        {

            view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, parent,false); 
            cache = new CacheRiga(); //inizializzo la cache
            cache.titolo = (TextView) view.findViewById(TITOLO); //title

            cache.immagini = (ImageView) view.findViewById(IMMAGINE);//collego descrizione


            view.setTag(cache);
        }
        else
        {
            cache = (CacheRiga) view.getTag(); 
        }

        cache.titolo.setText(titoli.get(pos)); //I set up the title

        //cache.immagini.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(pos));



        return view;
    }

    private class CacheRiga { // Cache class
        public TextView titolo; // Title cache
        public ImageView immagini; // Image cache
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: Posting code specific to your problem helps you get relevent answers quickly

Comment: the problem is that i can't find the problem! I can't understand if is in the adapter or in my MainActivity. So i can't find the solution and   this is why i need help.

Comment: could you please put a log in the getView method in the adapter , and print out if the bitmap is null or what ?
and print out the size of the bitmap List

Comment: the log says nothing..so i think is not null the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the ViewHolder stuff i.e. `CacheRiga` in your case. You can use. Universal Image Loader for this purpose.
Here's the link:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Oh, i never use this library.. Can you show me how can i implement in my code?

Answer (score 0):

use Universal image loader [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: I never use this library.. Can you show me how can i implement in my code?

Comment: you can download code from above mention link and you import that project in eclipse and foolow the step [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163680/how-to-use-this-library-in-android)

Comment: but taking my code..what have i to change if i use the Universal image loader library?